# Why is temperature a function of $y$ and $t$ only?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, flow, continuum-mechanics

Say you have an incompressible thermal conducting fluid contained between two infinite horizontal plates separated by a distance $H$.  Initially both the plates and the fluid are at rest at temperature $T_{0}$. At time $t=0$, the upper plate is raised to temperature $T_{1}>T_{0}$ and moved horizontally at speed $U$. Assuming laminar flow, why is temperature $T$ a function of $y$ and $t$ only?

Comment: plane symmetry?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Hopefully next time I can get at least the title correct...

Answer (score 0):

Why not?  You expect heat to transfer differently at another point on the plate.   Any point on plate one has a plate two at the same temperature, the same distance apart, and the same fluid in between.

The movement of the plate does not introduce a difference as the fluid in between still has the same history.